# How to reverse uncompleted animation and stop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I have two objects. When they touch each other they start to glow, but when they are separated they stop glowing.

Rather than glow turning off when separated, I want the glow to gradually decrease until off. How can I achieve this with Animation?

here is what I have tried:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) {
    if(other.gameObject == player.gameObject) {
        anim.SetFloat("Direction",1);
        anim.SetBool("touching",true);
        anim.Play("Heat");
    }
}

private void OnCollisionExit(Collision other) {
    if(other.gameObject == player.gameObject) {
        anim.SetFloat("Direction",-1);
        anim.SetBool("touching",false);
        anim.Play("Heat");
    }
}
```

[image]

This is almost what I want, but the objects immediately glow to full intensity and then they dim out. I don't want then to glow to full intensity.

PS: sorry for my Bad English. its not my native language

Comment: What happens if you don't call `Play` in `OnCollisionExit`?

Comment: So actually when they collide they glow to full intensity immediately right ? And when they separated they not glowing suddenly. And you want them to gradually decrease glowness ...Am I right?

Comment: @PraveenPanishetti yes

Comment: are you passing the Direction value as a parameter in the animation inspector for multiplier field ?